# Is it possible to extend a .scss-lint.yml config file

Tags: sass, lint, configuration-files

Is there supported syntax to extend a .scss-lint.yml config file in the same way that you can extend a .jshintrc config file?

My goal is to pull all config files from a node package.
So a jshint would look something like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/npm-package-name/shared/.jshintrc",
  "browser": true
}
```

I'm not sure how to pull off a scss-lint file.

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass?

Comment: its a linter config file for *.scss files.

Comment: Ok, but what does that have to do with Sass?  Are you having problems with Sass?

Comment: no issues with sass just getting a task runner to accept the config file - grunt-scss-lint for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now this is not possible. A workaround solution is to create a symlink to the scss-lint file.

```
ln -s path/to/symlink/filename filename
```

Comment: What about *"as of now"* 5 years later?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible through [`config-file`](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/blob/develop/docs/options/config-file.md) setting:

## Example:

```yaml
options:
  config-file: ./node_modules/@my-shared-repo/configuration/sass-lint.yml
  convention: hyphenatedbem
rules:
  class-name-format: 1
```

Comment: It works!. This should be changed as the accepted answer.